# Javascript Script Combining and Caching

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, gzip, httphandler

I am building a AJAX intensive web application (using ASP.NET, JQuery, and WCF web services) and am looking into building an HTTP Handler that handles script combining and compression for my JavaScript files and my CSS files. I know not combining the scripts is generally a less preferred approach, and I'm sure it's probably the way I will end up going, but my question is this...

Since so many of my JS files are due to the controls I use don't they get cached by the browser after the first load anyway? Since so many of these controls can be found on many of the pages of my web application is it actually faster to combine all of my scripts and serve that one file (which will vary for every page) or to serve the individual files which will get cached? I guess what I'm getting at is, by enabling script combining am I now losing part of the caching ability of the browser? I know I can cache the combined script, but the combined script will be different for every page whereas with the individual control scripts each one will be cached and the number of new scripts will be minimal for each page call.

Does this make any sense? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fewer number of JS files you serve, the faster your pages will be, due a smaller number of round trips to the server.  I would manually put all the common js code into one file (or as few files as possible), all the css code into one file etc., and not worry about using a handler to combine the files.  The handler is going to take processing time to combine the files, so you are going to pay that penalty also.  You can turn on gzip compression on IIS and have it handle that for you.  I would run something like [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)  on the Javascript files used in production.

If the handler changes the file contents from page to page, browsers won't be able to cache it.  If you are using SSL this point will be moot though as the browser won't cache the files anyway.

EDIT 
I've been corrected some browsers (like FF) can cache SSL content but not all.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize SSL plays a part in all of this. The web app is using SSL, and there are going to be LOTS of JS files that it needs to load in. I need to keep the files separate (at least for development) to maintain code separation and scalability. I could have Visual Studio handle some of the combining on compilation, but I really don't mind dealing with the penalty cost of the HttpHandler as I don't see it becoming a problem performance-wise.

Comment: Also, I believe Firefox 3+ now can cache CSS and JS files from SSL URL's.

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned: minify, gzip and turn on caching (set expire time and see to that you support etags) on the one static JS file you have and the one static CSS file you have. On top of this it's recommended to load your CSS files as early as possible and your JS files as late as possible (JS file loading is blocking other downloads and it's faster for the browser to render the page if it got the CSS as soon as possible). Sprites also help if you have many small images/icons. Loading static content from sub domains will help the browser to have more simultaneous downloads and you could drop all you cookies for those sub domains to lower the http header size.
You could consult [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) for performance analysis, it's a great tool!

Answer (score 0):

> generally a less preferred

is it for live js? I thinking of JavaScriptMVC which compresses all the code into one file when complied for production, not development... It's a heavy weight I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's better to combine all scripts. In this case you'll reduce http overhead. Minified controls scripts usually are quite small. In rare case when you are using quite large control you could not combine it to main js.